# I am doing a employee payslip program for school and my I am having trouble using while loops

Tags: python-3.x

```
print('Tax Category: (A: No Tax, B: 10%, C: 20%, D:29%, E: 35%')
taxbracket=input('Enter A, B, C, D, E:')
while taxbracket!='A' or taxbracket!='a' or taxbracket!='B' or taxbracket!='b' or taxbracket!='C' or taxbracket!='c' or taxbracket!='D' or taxbracket!='d' or taxbracket!='E' or taxbracket!='e':
    print('Error: please enter a correct value.')
    taxbracket=input('Enter A, B, C, D, or E:')
```

basically, I'm using a, b, c, d, and e (uppercase as well) to determine the type of tax the user wants(thats how the assignment wanted us to do it) and for me it just goes straight to my "error, please enter a correct variable" no matter what I input (including: a, b, c, d, e, or, A, B, C, D, E).

Comment: Try adding spaces between the variable name, and the the `!=` in the while loop.

Comment: change all `or` to `and` then it should work as you expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're connecting these statements with `or`. If one or more of them evaluate to `True` the loop will continue, and that will always be the case in the example you posted, because `taxbracket` cannot simultaneously be `'a'` and `'b'`.

A better way to do it would be to do the following, which also uses [`str.lower()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#string-methods).

```
print('Tax Category: (A: No Tax, B: 10%, C: 20%, D:29%, E: 35%')
taxbracket = input('Enter A, B, C, D, E:')

while taxbracket.lower() not in ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']:
    print('Error: please enter a correct value.')
    taxbracket = input('Enter A, B, C, D, or E:')
```